# How can I return a json depending on a few db searches?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a register script which checks if the submitted info is already in the DB or not.

Here is the routing of it

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
let {
    username,
    email,
    password,
    confirm_password
} = req.body;
console.log(req.body);
if (password !== confirm_password) {
    res.status(400).json({msg: "Password does not match."});
    return;
}

 User.findOne({username: username})
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user)
        if (user) {
            res.json({msg: "Username is already taken."})
            return;
        }

    }).catch(err => {console.log(err)});

 User.findOne({email: email})
    .then(user => {
        if (user) {
             res.json({
                msg: "Email is already taken."
            })

        }
    });
let newUser = new User({
    username,
    password,
    email
});
console.log("about to start hash")
return bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (!err) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) consoloe.log("**********************\n" ,err,"**********************\n");
            newUser.password = hash;
            console.log("before save")
            newUser.save().then(user => {
                console.log("all good")
                res.json({
                    msg:"good"
                });
            });

        })
    }
})
```

I just copied the "snippet" if you notice unclosed things that's the reason.

I tried adding those return statements but doesn't work and I think that that happends because it runs async so as it do both things at the same time its pointless (please explain me this since I don't get it at all)

The error it shows is

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

What I would like to do it to check if username and email arent there and in that case add them to the DB with the pass hashed (this works, but it's done ignoring other conditions so even if it is they are added again)

The response I'm getting right now is

> {
>      "msg": "Username is already taken."
>   }

I think the problem I have is that I don't understand at all how the "thread" works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the question itself both `findOne` will run asynchronously. The reason why you are also getting the message `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` because you have `res.json` in both `findOne` methods and once the promise is resolved both methods will try to send the response.

You can simply resolve this by using `async/await` and you can use `$or` operator and execute a single query instead of two separate query

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    const user = await User.findOne({$or: [{
        email: email
    }, {
        username: username
    }]});

    if (user) {
        if (user.username === username) {
            res.json({msg: "Username is already taken."})
            return;
        } else {
            res.json({ msg: "Email is already taken."})
            return;
        }
    }   
}
```